# What is the term for the separate view in iTerm2 where output is displayed, and how can it be disabled?

Tags: bash, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Whenever I type a command and an output is displayed, a within the same terminal (I'm using Iterm2) all my previous commands and other bash stuffs disappears and just the output is shown.

To exit this view, I need to press "q" and the previous inputs are shown again.

Q1: What is this view?
Q2: How can I disable this view to make the output show seamlessly alongside my commands?

Comment: It sounds like you are referring to the *alternate screen*, whose use is controlled by whatever command you happen to be running. There's no global setting. You might want to read http://shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: What is this view called?
A1: `alternate screen1

Q2: How can I disable this?
A2: You can disable the `alternate screen` in iTerm2 here:
`Profiles > Terminal > Disable save/restore alternate screen > (checked)`